# Live clock in Java Application

Tags: java

I have done :

```
import java.util.Timer;

public class Time
 {
 public static java.util.Date getDate()
 {
     java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    return date;         
 }

 public static java.text.SimpleDateFormat getFormat()
 {
     java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new  java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
     return format;
 }
 }
     ..... JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new    JLabel((Time.getFormat().format(Time.getDate())));
            lblNewLabel_4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            lblNewLabel_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
            lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(521, 13, 174, 28);
            panelMain.add(lblNewLabel_4);....
```

I want to make Jlabel which will show live date i tried this but obviously it doesnt work .

Comment: "Doesn't work" can mean many things.  Could mean it doesn't compile.  Could mean time doesn't display.  Could mean time doesn't update.  Could mean shows Chinese time and not local time.  Could mean an exception's been thrown.  Could mean it's in the wrong colour.  Could mean it's in the wrong language.  (Do you get my point?)

Answer (score 2):

This is the simple live dynamic clock java program it may help someone..done with lot of R&D.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;

public class timer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    Timer timer = new Timer();

         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
         {
            public void run()
            {
                Robot robbie;

                int second, minute, hour;
                Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                second = date.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                minute = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                hour = date.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                System.out.println("Current time is  " + hour + " : " + 
                minute +" : " + second);

                try
                {
                    robbie = new Robot();
                    robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                    robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
                    robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                    robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
                    robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                    robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                    robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
                    robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                    robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
                    robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                } catch (AWTException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 1 * 500, 1 * 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create and run a thread which does an infinite loop and which instantiates a new date at regular interval (here one second but according to your need, it could more or less)
From this new date, the label is updated

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LiveDateSwing extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label;
    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new LiveDateSwing();
    }

    public LiveDateSwing() {
      label = new JLabel(" ");
      add(label);
      setVisible(true);

      pack();

      Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          while (true) {
            Date date = getDate();
            String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
            label.setText(dateString);
            try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
    };

      Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
      t.start();
    }

    public static java.util.Date getDate() {
      java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
      return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple live digital watch with date created in applet. 
I tried it, it's working..

```java
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.text.*; 
import java.time.DayOfWeek; 
import java.time.LocalDateTime; 
import java.time.Month; 
import java.util.*;

public class Newdate implements Runnable {
    JFrame f;
    Thread t1 = null;
    int hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;
    String timeString = "";
    JButton b;

    public void DigitalWatch() {
        f = new JFrame();

        t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();

        b = new JButton();
        b.setBounds(50, 120, 200, 50);

        f.add(b);
        f.setSize(300, 400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {

                LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                Month month = currentTime.getMonth();
                int day = currentTime.getDayOfMonth();
                int year = currentTime.getYear();
                DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = currentTime.getDayOfWeek();

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                if (hours > 12)
                    hours -= 12;
                minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = cal.getTime();
                timeString = formatter.format(date);

                printTime();

                t1.sleep(10); // interval given in milliseconds
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void printTime() {
        b.setText(timeString);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Newdate dt = new Newdate();
        dt.DigitalWatch();

    }
}
```